# Display MSB to LSB

Tags: c, binary, printf, bit-shift

I'm having a hard time understanding my issue:

```
uint8_t nal_type=6;

for(i=7;i!=0;i--){
    printf("%d",(nal_type>>i)&0x01U);}
printf("\n");
```

I would expect the following  code to display the binary value from MSB  to LSB. But it displays the following:

```
0000011
```

Can someone enlighten me ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's just a simple mistake in your loop, so you're not seeing the LS bit (bit 0) - make it:

```
for (i = 7; i >= 0; i--)
{           ^^^^^^
    printf("%d", (nal_type >> i) & 0x01U);
}
```

This will then give the output as:

```
00000110
```

which I think is what you are looking for (MSB to LSB).

Comment: Thanks man, Sometimes it's hard to take a step back to see such mistakes !